# How to read and write to variables of an abstract class

Tags: java, class, variables, abstract

Put simply, I have an abstract class containing several variables and methods. Other classes extend this abstract class, yet when I try to read the private variable in the abstract class by calling getter methods inside the abstract class, it returns null as the value of the variable.

```
public class JavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewClass1 n1 = new NewClass1();
        NewClass2 n2 = new NewClass2();

        n1.setVar("hello");
        n2.print();

    }
}



public class NewClass1 {

    public String firstWord;

    public void setVar(String var) {
        firstWord = var;
    }

    public String getVar () {
        return firstWord;
    }

}



public class NewClass2 extends NewClass1{

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(makeCall());
    }

    public String makeCall() {
        return getVar();
    }

}
```

Still prints out null.

Comment: Please post the actual code.  As written, your `subclass` class won't compile.

Comment: why is "System.out.println(var2)" not in a method?

Comment: Just make the code compile (`String var2 = getVar1();`), place it in a method and it will work. There's no need for `protected`.

Comment: ok, I will post the relevent parts but I will have to remove it after a while.

Comment: Still won't compile. You're missing a closing brace and you're trying to print a void method.

Comment: You don't have a main, how can it even run. You never call `setFirstWord` so of course it is printing null

Comment: It does have a main, but this class isn't called from main. I have 4-5 classes before this is used. Edit: it is being set. I know because I have a println in the same method that prints the firstWord correctly.

Comment: Well write a main in this class to test it

Comment: execute() body isn't closed. did you override getFirstWord()?

Comment: @clcto : code now has a main. Removed the abstract. Still prints out null.

Answer (score 1):

Until the `String` is initialized, it will be null. You should probably have a constructor in the abstract class to set it.

```
public abstract class Command
{
     String firstWord; // = null 

     protected Command(){}

     protected Command( String w )
     {
         firstWord = w;
     }
     //...
}

public class Open extends Command
{
     public Open()
     {
         this( "your text" );
     }

     public Open( String w )
     {
         super( w );
     }

     // ...
}
```

---

If you need to modify the `firstWord` string everytime `execute()` is called then it may not be necessary to use a constructor with a `String` parameter (I added a default constructor above). However, if you do it this way then either

- You **must** make sure `setFirstWord()` is called before `getFirstWord()`, or,
- Handle the case when `getFirstWord()` returns `null`. This could be by simply using a default value (maybe determined by each subclass) or something else, like failing to execute.

As I do not know all the details of your implementation I cannot tell you further information.

Comment: Just added a constructor to Command. Now all of its subclasses want a constructor with parameters

Comment: What is this firstWord supposed to accomplish? Yes if you do not have a default constructor then all subclasses will have to call super() with the appropriate parameter. Is it different for each of the subclasses?

Comment: Each of the subclasses has an execute method, which overrides an execute method in the abstrast class (its super). The contents of the various execute methods needs to use the variables in the abstract class and be able to change it. Right now they cannot, so the program isn't working as it should.

Comment: I edited the code above so that firstWord is set before it is printed in the subclass. It still prints out null. This time I have also removed the abstract.